# seg fault when sending derived type data with allocatable array in mpi

Tags: fortran, mpi, allocatable-array

I'm trying to send a derived type data with allocatable array in mpi ad got a seg fault.

```
program test_type  

 use mpi

 implicit none

 type mytype
  real,allocatable::x(:)
  integer::a
 end type mytype

 type(mytype),allocatable::y(:)
 type(mytype)::z
 integer::n,i,ierr,myid,ntasks,status,request
 integer :: datatype, oldtypes(2), blockcounts(2) 
 integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: offsets(2)

 call mpi_init(ierr)
 call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,myid,ierr)
 call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,ntasks,ierr)

 n=2

 allocate(z%x(n))

 if(myid==0)then
  allocate(y(ntasks-1))
  do i=1,ntasks-1
   allocate(y(i)%x(n))
  enddo
 else
  call random_number(z%x)
  z%a=myid
  write(0,*) "z in process", myid, z%x, z%a
 endif

 call mpi_get_address(z%x,offsets(1),ierr)
 call mpi_get_address(z%a,offsets(2),ierr)
 offsets=offsets-offsets(1)

 oldtypes=(/ mpi_real,mpi_integer /)
 blockcounts=(/ n,1 /)

 write(0,*) "before commit",myid,offsets,blockcounts,oldtypes
 call mpi_type_create_struct(2,blockcounts,offsets,oldtypes,datatype,ierr) 
 call mpi_type_commit(datatype, ierr)
 write(0,*) "after commit",myid,datatype, ierr

 if(myid==0) then   
  do i=1,ntasks-1 
   call mpi_irecv(y(i),1,datatype,1,0,mpi_comm_world,request,ierr) 
   write(0,*) "received", y(i)%x,y(i)%a
  enddo
 else
  call mpi_isend(z,1,datatype,0,0,mpi_comm_world,request,ierr) 
  write(0,*) "sent"
  write(0,*) myid, z%x, z%a
 end if

 call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program
```

And this is what I got printed out running with 2 processes:

```
before commit           0                     0             -14898056
           2           1          13           7
 after commit           0          73           0
 z in process           1  3.9208680E-07  2.5480442E-02           1
 before commit           1                     0            -491689432
           2           1          13           7
 after commit           1          73           0
 received  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00           0
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
```

It seems to get negative address offsets. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this code.

Allocatable arrays with most Fortran compilers are like pointers in C/C++: the real object behind the array name is something that holds a pointer to the allocated data. That data is usually allocated on the heap and that could be anywhere in the virtual address space of the process, which explains the negative offset. By the way, negative offsets are perfectly acceptable in MPI datatypes (that's why `MPI_ADDRESS_KIND` specifies a *signed* integer kind), so no big problem here.

The bigger problem is that the offsets between dynamically allocated things usually vary with each allocation. You could check that:

```
ADDR(y(1)%x) - ADDR(y(1)%a)
```

is completely different than

```
ADDR(y(i)%x) - ADDR(y(i)%a), for i = 2..ntasks-1
```

(`ADDR` here is just a shorhand notation for the object address as returned by `MPI_GET_ADDRESS`)

Even if it happens the offsets match for some value(s) of `i`, that is more of a coincidence than a rule.

That leads to the following: the type that you construct using offsets from the `z` variable cannot be used to send elements of the `y` array. To solve this, simply remove the allocatable property of `mytype%x` if that is possible (e.g. if `n` is known in advance).

Another option that should work well for small values of `ntasks` is to define as many MPI datatypes as the number of elements of the `y` array. Then use `datatype(i)`, which is based on the offsets of `y(i)%x` and `y(i)%a`, to send `y(i)`.

A more severe issue is the fact that you are using non-blocking MPI operations and never wait for them to complete before accessing the data buffers. This code simply won't work:

```
do i=1,ntasks-1 
 call mpi_irecv(y(i),1,datatype,1,0,mpi_comm_world,request,ierr) 
 write(0,*) "received", y(i)%x,y(i)%a
enddo
```

Calling `MPI_IRECV` starts an asynchronous receive operation. The operation is probably still in progress by the time the `WRITE` operator gets executed, therefore completely random data is being accessed (some memory allocators might actually zero the data in debug mode). Either insert a call to `MPI_WAIT` inbetween the `MPI_ISEND` and `WRITE` calls or use the blocking receive `MPI_RECV`.

A similar problem exists with the use of the non-blocking send call `MPI_ISEND`. Since you never wait on the completion of the request or test for it, the MPI library is allowed to postpone indefinitely the actual progression of the operation and the send might never actually occur. Again, since there is absolutely no justification for the use of the non-blocking send in your case, replace `MPI_ISEND` by `MPI_SEND`.

And last but not least, rank 0 is receiving messages from rank 1 only:

```
call mpi_irecv(y(i),1,datatype,1,0,mpi_comm_world,request,ierr)
                              ^^^
```

At the same time, all other processes are sending to rank 0. Therefore, your program will only work if run with two MPI processes. You might want to replace the underlined `1` in the receive call with `i`.